# SQL inner join condition by actual date

Tags: sql

I need to join actual document to people. Documents has date issued (passport, for example).

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a8118/2/0

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE people 
(
    p_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    p_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(p_id)
);

INSERT INTO people (p_id, p_name)
VALUES (1, 'Name_1'),
       (2, 'Name_2');

CREATE TABLE documents 
(
    d_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    d_people INT(10) NOT NULL,
    d_date VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(d_id)
);

INSERT INTO documents (d_id, d_people, d_date)
VALUES (1, 1, '01.01.2022'),
       (2, 2, '01.12.2021'),
       (3, 1, '05.02.2022'),
       (4, 1, '10.02.2022'),
       (5, 2, '04.01.2022'),
       (6, 1, '20.01.2022');
```

Query: condition is select actual document when date is 21.01.2022, it must return d_id = 6:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people
INNER JOIN documents ON d_people = p_id
WHERE p_id = 1 AND ??? d_date 21.01.2022 ???
;
```

I need to do an inner join to return only this row:

[image]

Comment: How would you get `6` from `21.01.2022` when it's `d_date = '20.01.2022'`?

Comment: Why are you holding dates as varchar?

Comment: drum, document issued 20.01.2022. So on date "21.01.2022" it is actual.

Comment: NickW, this only for test.

Answer (score 1):

use this query:
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a8118/8)

```
SELECT * FROM people
INNER JOIN documents ON d_people = p_id
WHERE p_id = 1 and d_date='20.01.2022';
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But i want to select actual document (from document issued date to document validity date).
For example: Show me valid document for date 21.01.2022.
And it must be only one valid document d_id = 6